Error 404 Al usar Mp3 en github
estoy teniendo un problema con el archivo de sonido y github page
estoy armando una aplicacion en donde tengo un temporizador, cuando el temporizador termina o arranca llama a la funcion que debe reproducir un sonido. en local ANDA, pero cuando lo subo a github page me aparece el siguiente error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" que es el tipico error que no encontro el archivo, pero si entro al repo esl arhivo está, estoy seguro de me falta un paso pero no encuentro la soliución!
alguien sabe como podria solucionarlo?
Link de repo: https://github.com/Ivanveliz/TabataSpa
link de app: <ivanveliz.github.io/TabataSpa>
COMPONENTE DE AUDIO:
export default function playSound() {
  const audio = new Audio('../../sounds/start.mp3');
  return {
    play: function() {
      audio.play();
    }
  };


funcion de cuenta regresiva:
const sound = playSound();
function startCountDown() {
        if ($countDown > 1) {
            $countDown--;
            $containerDisplay.textContent = $countDown;
            if ($countDown === 3) {
                sound.play()
            }
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval); 
            
        }
    }
}


Puedes poner el link de la Github Page?? Claramente se ve que no encuentra el recurso (404). Peeeero, yo no estoy seguro si Github acepta audios en sus páginas; al ser solo estáticas debería de, pero como nunca lo he usado para eso, prefiero reservarme hasta comprobarlo

si obvio ya lo agrego! eso tambien empeze a dudar si github page acepta audios! jejeje por que en la doc no dice nada de mp3, soolo habla de imagenes!
ahi va el link https://ivanveliz.github.io/TabataSpa/

Tu problema definitivamente es el recurso ya que Github SI ACEPTA MP3
Prueba con esto en un proyecto nuevo (o en el que tienes)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Audio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="start.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="start.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>

Pon en la raíz el start.mp3 y veras que si se reproduce el sonido. En resumen, en tu proyecto hay un error 404 por no encontrar el sonido.
Sin tener claro desde donde enlazas el mp3, creería que el error viene de por esta línea

const audio = new Audio('../../sounds/start.mp3');

Pueda ser que estas "subiendo" menos o mas directorios, y sin saber exactamente tu estructura y desde donde tienes ese código JS para llamar al sonido de la carpeta sounds es complicado.
